# Form does not update on view and server in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, put

I have this bug in my web app. So, I have a form where when I edit the form it does not update on view and server. What I want to solve is when I edit my form, I want to update the view and the server. So, here is my code below. Please, check out my code if somethings wrong. Thanks in advance. Any Help?

> here is my code.

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);
            app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $window, people) {





        people.getUserInfo().then(function (response) {
            $scope.userInfo = response.data;
        });

        $scope.inactive = true;
        $scope.updateUser = function(person) {
            people.updateUser(person);
        };
        $scope.confirmedAction = function(person) {
            var index = $scope.userInfo.lawyers.map(function(e) {
                return e.id;
            }).indexOf(person.id);
            people.confirmUser(person.id).then(function(data){ });
            $scope.userInfo.lawyers.splice(index, 1);
            console.log($scope.userInfo.lawyers);
            $window.location.href = '#/lawyer';
        };
    });


});
```

> about

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="person in userInfo.lawyers | filter : {id: lawyerId}">
        <a class="back" href="#/lawyer">Back</a>
        <button type="button" class="edit" ng-show="inactive" ng-click="inactive = !inactive">
            Edit
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="submit" ng-show="!inactive" ng-click="updateUser(person)">Save</button>
        <a class="delete" ng-click="confirmedAction(person);" confirm-click>Confirm</a>
        <div class="people-view">
            <h2 class="name">{{person.firstName}}</h2>
            <h2 class="name">{{person.lastName}}</h2>
            <span class="title">{{person.email}}</span>
            <span class="date">{{person.website}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-view">
            <form>
                <fieldset ng-disabled="inactive">
                    <legend>Info</legend>
                    <b>First Name:</b>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="person.firstName">
                    <br>
                    <b>Last Name:</b>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="person.lastName">
                    <br>
                    <b>Email:</b>
                    <input type="email" ng-model="person.email">
                    <br>
                    <b>Website:</b>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="person.website">
                    <br>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> services to my backend

```
app.factory('people', function ($http) {
    var service = {};
    service.getUserInfo = function () {
        return $http.get('https://api-dev.mysite.com/admin/v1/lawyers');
    };
    service.confirmUser = function (lawyerId) {
        return $http.put('https://api-dev.mysite.com/admin/v1/lawyers/'+lawyerId+'/confirm');
    };
    service.updateUser = function (person) {
        return $http.put('https://api-dev.mysite.com/admin/v1/lawyers/'+ person.id, person);
    };
    return service;
});
```

> HomeController

```
  var isConfirmed = false;
  app.controller('HomeController', function($scope, people) {
   if (!isConfirmed) {
    people.getUserInfo().then(function (response) {

        $scope.userInfo = response.data;


     }, function (error) {
        console.log(error)

    });


  }
});
```

Comment: Does anything happen when you set `$scope.userInfo.lawyers` value outside of the `$scope.confirmedAction` function?

Comment: getting an error: `Cannot read property 'lawyers' of undefined`

Comment: How do you define `$scope.userInfo`? You need to set it outside of that function otherwise it remains undefined until the function is called.

Comment: @Mike In my `HomeController` shown in my updated question

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here.

- Data from the server is not bound to the controller which means it will not display in your view.
- The inputs to your form are binding to aliases and not any members of an actual scope
- After you submit changes to your data, you need to get updates from your server
- The `inactive` scope value is not updated after you save your data
  which means your 'Save' button won't hide after a form is submitted.

First step is populating your `$scope.userInfo` in your `MyCtrl` controller. When you set `$scope.userInfo` in your `HomeController` only `HomeController` has access to `$scope.userInfo` and not `MyCtrl`.

You need to change your code such that `MyCtrl` sets `$scope.userInfo` in it's own scope so that it has access to the data like so:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $window, people) {
    // This function will now be called so that it can get the userInfo
    // from the server and populate into the scope and give the controller
    // access.
    people.getUserInfo().then(function (response) {
        $scope.userInfo = response.data;
    });

   // ...

});
```

Now you need to actually bind the input of your `form` to the data in your scope.

```
         <form>
            <fieldset ng-disabled="inactive">
                <legend>Info</legend>
                <b>First Name:</b>
                <input type="text" ng-model="userInfo.lawyers[$index].firstName">
                <br>
                <b>Last Name:</b>
                <input type="text" ng-model="userInfo.lawyers[$index].lastName">
                <br>
                <b>Email:</b>
                <input type="email" ng-model="userInfo.lawyers[$index].email">
                <br>
                <b>Website:</b>
                <input type="text" ng-model="userInfo.lawyers[$index].website">
                <br>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

It's important to remember that Angular needs to bind to data in `$scope` before it will render changes in the DOM and using `person` from the `person in userInfo.lawyers` ng-repeat directive references an alias to a `person` and not to the actual data in the `userInfo` scope.

After you submit your changes you're going to want to update your list with new data from the server so include:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $window, people) {

    // ...

    $scope.updateUser = function(person) {

        people.updateUser(person)
            // Now get the new data.
            .then(function() {
                return people.getUserInfo();
            }).then(function (response) {
                // Apply the new data to the scope.
                $scope.userInfo = response.data;
            });

    };

    // ...
});
```

Finally for the `Save` button issues you need to be sure that `isactive` value of the scope is set appropriately for when you do and don't want it to appear in the DOM. Setting the value to `true` hides it while setting to `false` reveals it. The edit button already toggles this value for you but you can also toggle this value when the function you want it to execute completes. You can do this in the `updateUser` function:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $window, people) {

    // ...

    $scope.updateUser = function(person) {

        // Hide the save button
        $scope.inactive = true;

        people.updateUser(person)
            .then(function() {
                return people.getUserInfo();
            }).then(function (response) {
                $scope.userInfo = response.data;
            });

    };

    // ...
});
```

Additional resources for AngularJS scopes can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

Comment: I get an error in the console: `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` and `App is not defined`

Comment: After, the first bracket I do : `});`  and still it does not work.

Comment: @SuzyHakobyan updated to place `app` definition back at the top of the file and fixed syntax issue.

Comment: In the the questions there's an extra `});` at the bottom of the `App.js` file that needs to be deleted.

Comment: I have nothing gets update. When I click on save, the save button does not go back to edit disable mode

Comment: this is my save button `<button type="submit" class="submit" ng-show="!inactive" ng-click="updateUser(person)">Save</button>`

Comment: you want to move this to chat?

Comment: @SuzyHakobyan I just updated the code above so that it would update the `$scope.inactive` which should fix your problem but if not yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147114/discussion-between-mike-and-suzy-hakobyan).